# Chaining a Task returned by a function in a library

Tags: c#, async-await

The `async...await` in the code below feels wrong to me but I can't see a better alternative.

My actual code is much more complicated of course, this is a contrived example to illustrate the situation.

> Note that in the real code, the `Send` method is implemented in a
> library, so I can't change its signature.

The idea is that `SendAsync` returns a task that completes after the sending data task has completed, but the function that gets the data and the function that sends the data are both async.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

internal class Example
{
    public Task SendAsync()
    {
        return GetData()
            .ContinueWith(async serialize => await Send(serialize.Result));
    }

    private Task<Dto> GetData()
    {
        return Task.FromResult(new Dto { SomeProperty = "Test"});
    }

    private Task Send(Dto dto)
    {
        return Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine(dto.SomeProperty));
    }

    private class Dto
    {
        public string SomeProperty{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: The naming scheme of the example is poor. The `Send` method is asynchronous, so [it should be named](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap#naming-parameters-and-return-types) `SendAsync`. But this name is used by another asynchronous method in the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing `ContinueWith` is usually a bad sign. Consider instead:

```cs
public async Task SendAsync()
{
    await Send(await GetData());
}
```

(Note: IMO all the methods here should be named with the Async suffix)

Comment: There are people who argue that the `Async` suffix is not needed. However, *if* you go for that approach, it shouldn't be on `Send` either. It's all or none - you must be consistent :-)

Comment: @JakobBuskSørensen, alternative approach is to use `..Async` prefix only for methods which have corresponding synchronous version and skip it for methods without synchronous version.

Comment: @Fabio so your naming convention is dependent on never ever adding methods later, because that might invalidate your current naming scheme? That sounds like a bad idea...

Comment: @MarcGravell, right, but we choose different side of tradeoff. We prefer this instead of having verbose (`..Async()`) method names everywhere. With current IDE it  easy to see return type without suffix.  In our application we didn't introduce synchronous methods in addition to asynchronous yet.

Comment: Woah, so much Async suffix displeasure here. Leaving it off any method triggers my OCD and makes me mark any code review as a fail.

Comment: [Asynchronous programming - Important info and advice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async#important-info-and-advice)

Comment: I usually add the Async suffix to public methods, but IMHO is it not necessary for private. Classes should be kept small enough that you can easily see if private methods are async, and I think it makes the code more readable.

Comment: Hilariously, this code sample does not have the Async suffix https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async#extract-data-from-a-network

Comment: @bikeman868 there are contextual reasons for that: one is a controller action (and the name impacts routing and view resolution), and one is an event handler (thus `async void`). The methods in the same page that are neither of these: have the suffix

Answer (score 1):

You can "treat" asynchronous methods as synchronous when one method depends on result of another.

```
public async Task SendAsync()
{
    var data = await GetData();

    await Send(data);
}
```

With `await` next line of code will be executed when Task returned by the method is complete.